# For loop skipping duplicate index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just learning Python and I'm trying to make a small program where a user can enter in a list of numbers and then a target number. The program will then do a loop to add each of the listed numbers to see if any of the numbers can add to that target number and return the indices. However, if a user enters in a duplicate number, it skips that index altogether so I'm not sure why it's doing that or how to fix it.

```
elements = input('Please enter your elements: ')
given = list(map(int,elements.split(',')))
print(given)
target = int(input('Please enter your target number: '))

def get_indices_from_sum(target):
    for x in given:
        for y in given:
            if given.index(x) == given.index(y):
                continue
            target_result = x + y
            if target_result == target:
                result = [given.index(x), given.index(y)]
                print('Success!')
                return result
            else:
                continue
    if target_result != target:
        return 'Target cannot be found using elements in the given list.'
print(get_indices_from_sum(target))
```

For example, if someone entered in a list of 2,7,10,14 and a target number of 9, it would return [0,1]. On the other hand, when I tried a list of 2,3,3,10 and a target of 6, nothing comes back.

Comment: Instead of  list, you could input the given values into a set which contains only unique numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index method returns the first occurence's index therefore you are continuing  every time there is a duplicate.

> Python List index() The index() method searches an element in the list and returns its index. In simple terms, the index() method finds the given element in a list and returns its position. If the same element is present more than once, the method returns the index of the first occurrence of the element.

You need to rethink the rules you want to implement and go with something else.

If I were you I would iterate over `enumerate(given)` instead of iterating over `given`, this way you can compare indices correctly.

```
for idx, x in enumerate(given):
    for idy, y in enumerate(given):
        if idx == idy:
            continue
        target_result = x + y
        if target_result == target:
            result = [idx, idy]
            print('Success!')
            return result
        else:
            continue
if target_result != target:
    return 'Target cannot be found using elements in the given list.'
```

Comment: Ah I see. Can you possibly explain the "for idx, x" part? Not sure I understand what that's doing. Is it basically saying "for position idx, value x"?

Comment: `enumerate(given)` will return a `tuple` with two objects, the current index of the array and the current value of that index. Here this tuple is just being unpacked into two named variables. so `idx` will point to the current value of the index and `x` will point to the current value of the index

Comment: Got it. So basically with enumerates, I'll need declare 2 variables in the for loop. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes the first tracks the index and the second tracks the value